# How to get good HVAC quotes?

Tags: hvac, heating, air-conditioning, central-heating, central-air

My natural gas furnace and air conditioner are 20 years old. I plan to gather quotes to replace them both. What do I need to do so that I get good quotes?

I've heard HVAC contractors talk in an online forum and many said Manual J calculations are a must, that people shouldn't get more than three quotes (it wastes their time), that people should get recommendations from friends and neighbors, that the quality of the install makes more difference than the brands or models, and that I should let them know what I'm looking for in the new system.

What would you recommend?

Comment: There are some key issues depending on location - weather related and jurisdiction and what changes are needed for a new system. Where are you? What type of furnace do you have now? Specifically 80%,90% etc. Electric or gas hot water? Any idea of current system size? (Ton cooling, btu heating)

Comment: Recommendations from local friends and neighbours are probably the best.  The locals know how the locals do the work.  Then three to five quotes from the best.  Know what you want.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Will those kinds of specifics help drive my strategy for finding the best quotes to fit my needs? At this point I'm more interested in knowing _how_ to go about finding the best installation and company for my needs, not necessarily _what_ the best HVAC system is for me. Feel free to push back on that

Comment: Yes, because then you can start off with an idea of the types of systems and scope of work involved. Makes you an educated consumer which saves the jbac companies some time (they don't have to educate you as much) and let's them know you won't get fooled by buzzwords.